# Have a border with padding in top and bottom in table-cell in IE11

Tags: html, css, border, internet-explorer-11

I want to have a css table with a table-cell in it that has a border on its left hand side (see fiddle). It works by absolute positioning and use top and bottom value in Chrome. 
But in IE11 (and older I guess) the border isn't shown at all. What is the best solution for accomplishing this and have it work in all browser (down to IE9)?
https://jsfiddle.net/jhparj52/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="the-table">
    <div class="cell-containing-border">
        <div class="the-border"></div>
    <div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="cell-not-containing-border"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.the-table {
    display: table;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 80px;
}

.cell-containing-border {
    display:table-cell;
    position: relative;  
}

.the-border {
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4px solid black;
}

.cell-not-containing-border {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 40px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding padding seems to fix the issue:

```css
.the-table {
  display: table;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
}

.cell-containing-border {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

.the-border {
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0;
}

.cell-not-containing-border {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-table">
  <div class="cell-containing-border">
    <div class="the-border">

    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-not-containing-border">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to vertically align the border to middle, as it does for top/bottom 10px.

Comment: And it would be the same as setting the height explicitly right?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find is to set an explicit height to the border. With a fixed height to the parent it's possible to calculate the height in order to get same padding in top and bottom.

```css
.the-table {
  display: table;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
}
   
.cell-containing-border {
  display:table-cell;
  position: relative;  
}
    
.the-border {
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  height: 60px;
}
    
.cell-not-containing-border {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 40px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="the-table">
  <div class="cell-containing-border">
    <div class="the-border"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-not-containing-border"></div>
</div>
```